# Why does re.match() not function appropriately here?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bioinformatics, biopython

I am trying to parse a pdb file (Protein Data Bank) using Python.

These kind of lines in the file are causing trouble:

**ATOM   4811  HB2ASER A 329      41.099  -2.338  37.406  0.74 12.06           H**

They otherwise are in this format:

**ATOM   4810  HA BSER A 329      39.458  -2.064  39.518  0.26 11.30           H**

Here, as visible, the 3rd and 4th elements in the list will be joined and be considered a single element when I split the list.

Here is how I am trying to overcome this:

```
for line in pdbfile:
        line_list = line.split()
        id = line_list[0]
        
        if id == 'ATOM':
            s_no = line_list[1]
            atom = line_list[3]
            chain_id = line_list[4]
            if len(chain_id) > 1:
                line_list.insert(0, 0)
                match = re.match(r"([a-z]+)([0-9]+)([a-z]+)", atom, re.I)
                if match:
                    atom = match.groups()[-1]

            x_coord = line_list[6]
            y_coord = line_list[7]
            z_coord = line_list[8]

            with open('coordinates.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
                # print(chain_id)
                writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
                writer.writerow([s_no, pdb_id, resolution, atom, chain_id,
                                 x_coord, y_coord, z_coord])
```

When I run this same code in the shell, it produces the right output. But when I run the program, there is no change in the csv file I am trying to create. The result is:

[image: csv result]

So basically, the if statement above is not doing what it does in the shell. Why?

Comment: check your paths when your running the program, since everything works fine in the shell

Comment: Is the problem that it doesn't write anything to the file or that it doesn't correctly parse the format? Because if it's the former, your question has nothing to do with `re.match`

Comment: Shouldn't the path be fine, because the other lines are added as desired?

Comment: It writes the image above to a csv file, but the lines that are of the given format are not parsed properly, as shown in the middle 4 lines in the image.

Comment: https://github.com/haddocking/pdb-tools/blob/master/pdbtools/pdb_tidy.py

Comment: we need input file